# How to dynamically update RecyclerView within AndroidView in Android Compose

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose

I want the RecyclerView to dynamically change when the list is altered.

The view is recomposed based on the AndroidView.update expression. However nothing I have tried works.
I am not familiar with RecyclerViews and I think that is the issue.

Any ideas?

```
 AndroidView(
        factory = {

            // Logic for inflating a RecyclerView in a normal Android View System
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(it)
                .inflate(R.layout.edit_list_xml_screen_layout, null, false)

            val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.taskListRV)
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(it)

            val adapter = TaskRecyclerViewAdaptor(it, taskList)
            // adapter.setClickListener()
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
                DividerItemDecoration(
                    it,
                    DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
                )
            )
            
            recyclerView                    // Return recyclerView
        },
        update = {
            /* TODO dynamically update recycler view */
        }
```

Bonus points if someone can tell me what argument to add to `adapter.setClickListener()`

Comment: did you successfully inflate/add the RecyclerView into Compose?

Comment: I can inflate the RecyclerView but cannot add to it dynamically. New entries are only visible when the entire RecyclerView is re-inflated.

Comment: in our case, we've magically succeed inflating the RV, will update as an answer later, please ping/mention me here again as a reminder

Comment: @mochadwi I am all ears.

Comment: added as an answer, hopefully it also solve your problems :pray

Answer (score 3):

In our case:

1. We use `ViewBinding` in our `Fragment`, therefore we need to remove the parent group first (cmiiw in this part), we use this ViewBindingDelegate [here](https://github.com/androidbroadcast/ViewBindingPropertyDelegate/)
2. The click listener also passed as argument, see `onItemClick`
3. In our case, the recyclerview setup was done in `OurFragment` instead of inside Compose screen, so the compose screen only receive the `recyclerView: (Context) -> View` lambda to inflate the view inside Compose screen `OurComposeScreen.kt`

Our Fragment

```kotlin
// OurFragment.kt

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
       initBanner()
    }

    private fun initBanner() {
        binding.banner.setContent {
            BannerListScreen(
                recyclerView = { context ->
                    recyclerViewSetup(
                        context = context,
                        onItemClick = ::recyclerViewClick,
                    )
                },
            )
        }
    }

// ...

    private fun recyclerViewSetup(
        context: Context,
        // modify this to your usecase, as we use RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener, but this is also possible to use a simple lambda () -> Unit
        onItemClick: (Context, MyAdapter) -> RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener,
    ): RecyclerView = with(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_custom_xml, null, false)) {
        val recyclerView = RecyclerView(context).apply {
            if (parent != null) (parent as ViewGroup).removeView(this) // we need to remove the parent group as it'll inflate the view twice if added in compose
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context).apply {
                orientation = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL
            }

            adapter = MyAdapter(...)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            addOnItemTouchListener(onItemClick(context, adapter))
        }

        recyclerView
    }


    private fun recyclerViewClick(
        context: Context,
        adapter: MyAdapter,
    ) = RecyclerItemClickListener(
        context,
        RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener { view, position ->
            val b = adapter.getItem(position) // todo something with the click listener
        }
    )
```

Our Compose screen:

```kotlin
// OurComposeScreen.kt
@Composable
internal fun BannerReminder(
    // .....
    recyclerView: (Context) -> View,
) {
    Column(
        // omitted....
    ) {
        AndroidView(
            modifier = /* ... */,
            factory = { context -> recyclerView(context) }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a clever solution. I wish I would have thought of this :D

Answer (score 2):

Here, the update block gets called whenever there is change in list "size". Like an item add, remove or clearing list. Considering "taskList" - initially the recycler view is populated on given list and both factory and update block are called for first time.

First update list:

```
taskList.addAll(itemsToBeAdded)
```

Notify adapter:

```
update = {
     (it.adapter as TaskRecyclerViewAdaptor).notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

To be specific on add or remove item, you can notify it like

UpdateList as:

```
taskList.add(item)
itemposition = position
```

or

```
taskList.remove(item)
itemposition = position
```

Then in update:

```
 update = {
     (it.adapter as TaskRecyclerViewAdaptor).notifyItemRemoved(itemposition)
    }
```

Every time on change in list size, the update method gets called.